# Is it possible to require user rights when opening second form ,when application run as administrator?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, winforms, wpf-controls

I know you can create a manifest file to specify access level administrator for the whole application. But is it possible to only require it for a specific form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

What you can do: Let your process run without elevation.
When you discover that elevation is required but your process does not run elevated, restart the process (Process.Start) with the "runas" verb and maybe some command line option that you can evaluate in the newly started process to immediately open the form.

```
if (!RunningElevated())
{
    // restart as elevated process
    ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        UseShellExecute = true,
        Verb = "runas",
        WorkingDirectory = Environment.CurrentDirectory,
        FileName = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location,
        Argument = "--open MyForm" // has to be evaluated on the startup code
    };
    var process = Process.Start(psi);
    if (process != null)
        Application.Current.Shutdown(0); // this is for WPF
}
```